# How to find out how many variables can be passed to a selector.

Tags: ios, swift

i have encountered an example of a function which contains a selector parameter.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage, Any?, Selector?, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

I create a function that has three parameter for UIImageWriteToSavePhotoAlbum Function

```
func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    // do something here
}
```

and then i pass the function to the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function like this

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, writer, #selector(PhotoWriter.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

Here, we can see that the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function is passing three parameters to the selector.

But, how do we find out how many parameters are passed into a selector such as UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum, so that we can create a corresponding function that has the same number of parameters?

Comment: You can't pass any input arguments to a function using a selector.

Comment: The documentation for [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum) tells you what signature the selector should have. It's probably the same for every function that gets a callback parameter.

Comment: @DávidPásztor yup, i understand.. What i am asking is, for example, we all know that UiButton has an addTarget function that requires a selector. But we know by default the addTargaet function will pass a parameter, which is UIButton, to its selector. SO we can create the function as func buttonTapped(button : UIButton).. But how do we know how many parameters can be passed to a selector in other cases?

Comment: @progammingBeignner: You'll have to consult the documentation in each case. [`addTarget`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) is a special case because it accepts actions with [0, 1, or 2 parameters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol#1943645).